# Windows 7 not working after fresh install

Tags: windows-7, drivers, usb-flash-drive

I am configuring an old laptop to give to a friend (ThinkPad E420) and recently bought an SSD and Windows 7 Home Premium OEM DVD to install.  The actual installation worked fine, but when it started up for the first time, it doesn't recognize any network related drivers.

I went to the Lenovo site on my MacBook Air, downloaded an Ethernet driver, copied it to a USB, and tried to load it on the TP with the USB drive (formatted Mac style).

Problem is the Thinkpad does not recognize the USB drive. It is not listed in windows explorer. What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried formatting the USB with FAT32, and try again? Or if you have other USB disk / USB external HDD that you can try? Burn the drivers (probably download all of them from your Mac) into a CD/DVD?

Comment: Thank you, that worked-formatting the USB stick as FAT32 did the trick.

Comment: Your information solves the problem :) You had just the right information "Formatted Mac Style" and plugged into Windows machine - yep.

Comment: @Darius could you please add that as answer then ;)

Comment: @Op: Could you adjust the title? It seems that windows 7 is working fine after a fresh installation.  You just miss some drivers.  Right now this is like "My car will not start" because I do not have a tomtom. (The car starts fine).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately HFS+ (Mac Format) is not readable by Windows. You should format the USB in FAT32 which is read/writable by both Mac and Windows.

Comment: Why did you write it like that?

Comment: Feel free to edit.. Might have something to do with me writing answers at 7AM without sleep.. or coffee..